# Git Submodules vs. Cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, dependency-management, git-submodules, cocoapods

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using Cocoapods vs. Git Submodules? I am aware that there are several differences, but I would like to find out more about the advantages and disadvantages of using either system. Thanks!

Comment: opinion based questions are off topic.

Comment: it's a question about the list of differences, thus they are expected to be objective and technical. how come the moderator decided that it is opinion based?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git submodules shouldn't be used for dependancy management. I suggest you to use Cocoapods.

### Git Submodule

**Pros**

- Basically a one liner to initiate it, no need for extra files / configuration.

**Cons**

- You can't specify target directories, you always have to clone the whole repository.
- When the repository moves you have to manually update it.
- You have to check in the actual dependancies.

### Cocoapods

**Pros**

- Only clones the directories you need.
- Easy to update / maintain.
- You doesn't have to check in the whole dependancy tree, you just need to check in the `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock`. Every maintainer can fetch the dependancies on there own.

**Cons**

- Depends on the Podfile in your Spec repository or the main spec repository.
- Depends on an external tool.

You can read more about Cocoapods [here](http://cocoapods.org/).

Comment: Dependencies are one of the biggest problems of pods. Using a pod to get one simple functionality often leads to including several pods with megabyte resources. Sometimes it's easier to just take the functionality you require and copy-paste it into your own code.